# Relative Line Height Not Cascading Down To <tables>

Tags: html, css

I'm setting a global font-size and line-height on my `<body>` tag, so all default body copy is `14px` and a `1.3em` line-height.

The problem is as I have tables that have a larger font-size, and instead of inheriting a relative line-height, it's taking the computed value from the `<body>` tag. As a result the text overlaps:

Here is a code pen: https://codepen.io/thedigitalmc/pen/xxZJjyy

```
<body>
<style type="text/css">
body {
  font-size:13px;
  line-height:1.3em
}

td {
  font-size:30px
}
</style>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>This Is Text<br>On Two Lines</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Is there a better way to do this, I don't really want to do `body * {line-height:1.3em}` but it seems the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the relative em unit if you want the line height to maintain a constant ratio with the font size. Simply set `line-height: 1.3` instead.

```css
body {
  font-size:13px;
  line-height:1.3;
}

td {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>This Is Text<br>On Two Lines</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```